# Django: Allowing a User to vote only once

Tags: django

I want a user to be able to vote only once. I know to create another Model called "Vote" to have a productID and userID and check to see if the User had a vote casted for the productID already then it should not be able to upvote. But I do not know how to implement it.

Below is part of the models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/')
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/')
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:100]

class Vote(models.Model):
    productID = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And below is part of the views.py

```
@login_required
def upvote(request,product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=product_id)
        product.votes_total += 1
        product.save()
        return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your upvote method, get Vote object as well with productId and userId.

```
vote = Vote.objects.get(productID=product_id,userID=user_id)
```

if vote is found do not update total_votes on product else update total_votes.

Please note Vote.objects.get will raise a DoesNotExist exception if it doesn't find a row matching the conditions.

```
try:
    vote = Vote.objects.get(productID=product_id,userID=user_id)
except Vote.DoesNotExist:
    vote = None
if vote is not None:
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=product_id)
    product.votes_total += 1
    product.save()
    return redirect('/products/' + str(product.id))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am having rouble adding the user_id. I know I have to go to the urls.py to add <int:user_id> but it does not seem to work.

Comment: share your route file urls.py

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to maintain a many-to-many relation between user and product. Like so:

```
users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

When a user upvote add that user to the instance of product

```
product.users.add(user)
```

And to get total upvotes, you can do like:

```
product.users.count()
```

Even if you add a user more than once, it will not increase count.

```
product.users.add(user)
product.users.add(user)
product.users.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to [arp's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1681281/arp) answer, I got it to work by changing it to

```
try:
    vote = Vote.objects.get(productID=product_id, userID=request.user)
  except Vote.DoesNotExist:
    vote = None

  if vote is None:
    # find product by id and increment 
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    vote = Vote(product=product, user=request.user)
    product.votes_total += 1 
    vote.save()
    product.save()
```

So the changes would be finding the user with request.user and then making sure to create a new Vote instance connecting the user and the product.